# os.system (cmd /all >file) gives an empty file, if i run the command directly in the command prompt I am getting the output to text file

Tags: python, cmd, os.system, vmrun

I am trying to find all the VM's running using "vmrun list" command and i want the output in the text file.

```
import os
os.system("C:\\Program\ Files\ (x86)\\VMware\VMware\ VIX\\vmrun /all >C:\\Users\\xyz\\Documents\\qw.txt ")
```

When i run the same command in the command prompt i am getting a file with the command prompt output, but when i do the same thing in python i am getting an empty file.
What can i do to get the output to the file from python script??

Comment: i wonder if that command is running under a different user scope when you run it by hand vs by code

Comment: thanks I have changed the current working directory to VIX directory and it works.

Comment: By default [`system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) uses `cmd.exe /c command`. Apparently you haven't read the documentation for how `cmd /c` [handles quoting](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-cmd.html). Wrap the whole command line in an extra set of double quotes. Or pass the command string (not a list) to `subprocess.call` with `shell=True`, or use `subprocess.check_output` and write the file yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look on subprocess module , by example command getoutput.